# Styling icons to Fit in Textinput

Tags: react-native

How do I style this correctly?

I am trying to use an icon i got from Flat icons in the `Textinput` field. its a React native CLI project so the image is saved somewhere inside the folder assets.
Here is the main challenge its placed above the input textbox which is not supposed to be so.

The image Looks something like this :

[image: example.png]

I started to wonder what i am doing wrong. My code looks something like this

```
/* eslint-disable prettier/prettier */
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View , Image, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, Alert, Linking} from 'react-native';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/SimpleLineIcons';

class Login extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        user: '',
        password: ''
    };

    DummyLogin = () =>
    {
        alert('I am a Dummy Login!');
    }

    FunctionLogin = () =>
    {
        const {user} = this.state;
        const {password} = this.state;
        fetch('https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.000webhostapp.com/rest/login.php',{
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
              },
              body: JSON.stringify({
                user: user,
                password: password
              })
        }).then((response) =>response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {
            if(responseJson === 'OK')
            {
                this.props.navigation.navigate('Announcements');
            }
            else
            {
                Alert.alert(responseJson);
            }
        }).catch((error) =>{
            console.error(error);
        });
    }
  }

  render() 
  {
      return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Image source={{uri:'asset:/logo/436146d3-d290-459b-ae8a-bc5b07eacea1_200x200.png'}}
        style={styles.logo} />

        <Text style={{textAlign:'left',fontSize:40,fontWeight:'bold' ,color: '#030303'}}> Sign In</Text>

        <View>
        <Image
          source={{uri: 'asset:/icons/user.png'}}
          style={styles.imageStyle}
        />
            <TextInput
            placeholder = " Account Number"
            onChangeText={user => this.setState({user})}
            style={styles.input}
            keyboardType='numeric'
            value={this.state.myNumber}
            maxLength={10} 
            />
        </View>

        <View>
        <Image
          source={{uri: 'asset:/icons/lock.png'}}
          style={styles.imageStyle}
        />
            <TextInput
            placeholder = " Password"
            onChangeText={password => this.setState({password})}
            style={styles.input}
            secureTextEntry={true} />
        </View>

        <Text style={{color: '#030303', textAlign: 'center', alignSelf:'stretch'}}
        onPress={() => Linking.openURL('http://google.com')}>
        Forgot Password?
        </Text>

        <View style={styles.space} />
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {DummyLogin();}} style={styles.button}>
        <Text style={styles.loginbtn}> Login </Text>
         </TouchableOpacity>
         <View style={styles.space} />
         <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {DummyLogin();}} style={styles.Regbutton}>
        <Text style={styles.loginbtn2}> Register </Text>
         </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container:{
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent :"center",
        alignItems:"center"
    },

    input:{
        width:300,
        height:55,
        margin:10,
        fontSize : 16,
        borderBottomColor:'#030303',
        borderBottomWidth: 1,
        marginBottom: 30,
    },

    button:{
        width:300,
        height: 52,
        padding:10,
        borderRadius:10,
        backgroundColor:'#030303',
        alignItems: 'center'
    },

    Regbutton:{
        width:300,
        height:52,
        padding:10,
        borderRadius:10,
        backgroundColor:'#ffffff',
        alignItems: 'center',
        borderWidth : 2,
        borderColor: '#030303'
    },


    loginbtn:{
        color:'#ffff',
        fontSize : 20,
        fontWeight : 'bold'
    },

    loginbtn2:{
        color:'#030303',
        fontSize : 20,
        fontWeight : 'bold'
    },

    logo:{
    width:150,
    height:150
    },

    space: {
        width: 10, 
        height: 10,
      },

      imageStyle: {
        padding: 5,
        margin: 2,
        height: 15,
        width: 15,
        resizeMode: 'stretch',
        marginBottom: 8,
        marginTop : 8,
        alignItems: 'center',
      },
});

export default Login;
```

**Updated Source Code**

Here is the updated source code

```
/* eslint-disable prettier/prettier */
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View , Image, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, Alert, Linking} from 'react-native';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/SimpleLineIcons';

class Login extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        user: '',
        password: ''
    };

    DummyLogin = () =>
    {
        alert('I am a Dummy Login!');
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Home');
    }

    FunctionLogin = () =>
    {
        const {user} = this.state;
        const {password} = this.state;
        fetch('https://xxxxxxxxxxxxx.000webhostapp.com/rest/login.php',{
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
              },
              body: JSON.stringify({
                user: user,
                password: password
              })
        }).then((response) =>response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {
            if(responseJson === 'OK')
            {
                this.props.navigation.navigate('Announcements');
            }
            else
            {
                Alert.alert(responseJson);
            }
        }).catch((error) =>{
            console.error(error);
        });
    }
  }

  render() 
  {
      return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Image source={{uri:'asset:/logo/436146d3-d290-459b-ae8a-bc5b07eacea1_200x200.png'}}
        style={styles.logo} />

        <Text style={{textAlign:'left',fontSize:40,fontWeight:'bold' ,color: '#030303'}}> Sign In</Text>

        <TextInput
            placeholder = " Account Number"
            onChangeText={user => this.setState({user})}
            style={styles.input}
            keyboardType='numeric'
            value={this.state.myNumber}
            maxLength={10} 
            />

        <TextInput
            placeholder = " Password"
            onChangeText={password => this.setState({password})}
            style={styles.input}
            secureTextEntry={true} />

        <Text style={{color: '#030303', textAlign: 'center', alignSelf:'stretch'}}
        onPress={() => Linking.openURL('http://google.com')}>
        Forgot Password?
        </Text>

        <View style={styles.space} />
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {DummyLogin();}} style={styles.button}>
        <Text style={styles.loginbtn}> Login </Text>
         </TouchableOpacity>
         <View style={styles.space} />
         <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {DummyLogin();}} style={styles.Regbutton}>
        <Text style={styles.loginbtn2}> Register </Text>
         </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container:{
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent :"center",
        alignItems:"center"
    },

    input:{
        width:300,
        height:55,
        margin:10,
        fontSize : 16,
        borderBottomColor:'#030303',
        borderBottomWidth: 1,
        marginBottom: 30,
    },

    button:{
        width:300,
        height: 52,
        padding:10,
        borderRadius:10,
        backgroundColor:'#030303',
        alignItems: 'center'
    },

    Regbutton:{
        width:300,
        height:52,
        padding:10,
        borderRadius:10,
        backgroundColor:'#ffffff',
        alignItems: 'center',
        borderWidth : 2,
        borderColor: '#030303'
    },


    loginbtn:{
        color:'#ffff',
        fontSize : 20,
        fontWeight : 'bold'
    },

    loginbtn2:{
        color:'#030303',
        fontSize : 20,
        fontWeight : 'bold'
    },

    logo:{
    width:150,
    height:150
    },

    space: {
        width: 10, 
        height: 10,
      },

      imageStyle: {
        flexDirection:'row',
        justifyContent:'center',
        padding: 5,
        margin: 2,
        height: 15,
        width: 15,
        resizeMode: 'stretch',
        marginBottom: 8,
        marginTop : 8,
        alignItems: 'center',
      },
});

export default Login;
```

Comment: so what was it supposed to look like?

Comment: @kenmistry, the image is supposed to be on the same row as the textinput boxes

Comment: i see. you can try passing the `flexDirection` prop with `row` value to the parent view, and it should display both items on the same row.

Comment: done that, still the same issue. Let me share updated source code

Answer (score 0):

@Evans, what I meant was the inner parent `<View>`, like this:

```
<View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
  <Image
    source={{uri: 'asset:/icons/user.png'}}
    style={styles.imageStyle}
  />
  <TextInput
    placeholder = " Account Number"
    onChangeText={user => this.setState({user})}
    style={styles.input}
    keyboardType='numeric'
    value={this.state.myNumber}
    maxLength={10} 
  />
</View>
```

If it still doesn't work, you may consider adding in the `flex` props for both `<Image>` and `<TextInput>` components.

Comment: Still has the same issue, does not align correctly

Comment: @Evans i see. is the above your finalised code? i will try to replicate on my end to see what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```js
<View style={{paddingHorizontal:fontSizes.containerSpace,borderRadius:fontSizes.containerSpace/2,marginBottom:fontSizes.containerSpace,borderColor:'#E3E3E3',borderWidth:.85,width:(width - (fontSizes.containerSpace * 2)),backgroundColor: '#FFF',}}> 
                        <TextInput 
                            style={{height:width * 0.123,fontSize:fontSizes.bodySize * .80,fontFamily:fontFamilies.paraFont,color:'#2C2C2C'}}
                            autoCorrect={false}
                            autoCapitalize='none'
                            value={this.props.login.password}
                            secureTextEntry={this.state.passShowEnable}
                            onChangeText={(text)=>this.props.changeMCode2(text)}
                            placeholder="Enter your Password"
                            placeholderTextColor="#E3E3E3" />
                        <View style={{position: 'absolute',right:fontSizes.containerSpace * 1.5, top:0, height:width * 0.123, justifyContent:'center', backgroundColor: '#FFF',}}>
                            {
                                this.state.passShowEnable == true ?
                                <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=> this.setState({passShowEnable: false})}>
                                    <CustomIcon
                                        iconsName = {'unlock'}
                                        colorIcon = {themeColor.primary}
                                        iconSize  = {fontSizes.iconSize * .8}
                                        iconType  = 'feather' />
                                </TouchableOpacity>
                                :
                                <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=> this.setState({passShowEnable: true})}>
                                    <CustomIcon
                                        iconsName = {'lock'}
                                        colorIcon = {themeColor.primary}
                                        iconSize  = {fontSizes.iconSize * .8}
                                        iconType  = 'feather' />
                                </TouchableOpacity>
                            }
                        </View>
                   </View>
```